# Use `With` Tag to invert a boolean in Django Template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to pass a value to an `include` tag that is the OPPOSITE of a variable passed in.

This is what I tried (basically):

```
{% with s_options as not disp %}
    {% include "e.html" with show_options=s_options only %}
{% endwith %}
```

Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit of a hack using the built in filter [yesno](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno), but it works:

```
{% with reversed_value=original_value|yesno:',True' %}
    {# Do something #}
{% endwith %}
```

Note the comma before `'True'`. The way it works is that `yesno` will return an empty string if the original value is `True`, which will evaluate as False if you're doing any boolean operations on it.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I just made a new filter:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name="not_value")
def not_value(true_value):
    return not true_value
```

And then did:

```
{% load not_value %}
{% with s_options=disp|not_value %}  {# WILL NOT WORK WITH "as" #}
    {% include "e.html" with show_options=s_options only %}
{% endwith %}
```

Note that, possibly, this might work as well (though I have not tried):

```
{% include "e.html" with show_options=s_options|not_value only %}
```

Comment: That's a pretty good solution. The with tag only supports the syntax `{% with foo=bar %}` and the older format `{% with foo as bar %}`. It's not possible to add to/subtract from/negate the included variable unless you use a filter, as you have done.

Comment: @Alasdair I also noticed when testing that it only accepts filters when using the newer `{% with foo=bar %}`, otherwise it throws an error.

Comment: Yes, I noticed your comment in your answer about that. I guess there's not much you can do apart from using the newer format.

Comment: @MikeG I like your solutions, but I m curious if `{% with not s_options=disp %}` would work.