# Negating a boolean in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to negate a python boolean variable in a template using Django?
I've tried both of the following:

```
<td>{{ !variable_name }}</td>
<td>{{ not variable_name }}</td>
```

But both gave me a TemplateSyntaxError.

I realize that I could do:

```
<td>{% if variable_name %} False {% else %} True {% endif %}</td>
```

But this seems really clunky. I was hoping there might be a cleaner method.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What about the [yesno](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) template tag?

```
{{ value|yesno:"False,True" }}
```

Comment: Ah, this looks great. Didn't know about this one.

Comment: I was looking through the docs some more and noticed that one (didn't come up in my searching obviously). It's shorter than using a whole if, but it seems a little hacky. Turns out I actually need to do a bit of formatting in either case though, so this is probably the best option

Comment: Strictly speaking this isn't reversing the boolean, as `yesno` returns a string.  That's fine as long as you don't want to do a further test of the 'reversed' value.  In this case, "False", as a string, will evaluate to True.

Comment: If you need to do a boolean evaluation of the reversed value, you could do {{ value|yesno:",True" }}.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30075273/1005499

Answer (score 23):

"not" should work, according to this example from the Django docs:

```
{% if not athlete_list %}
    There are no athletes.
{% endif %}
```

You can find the example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators

If you want to directly get the string representation of a boolean, i'm afraid you have to go what you describe as clunky. {{ variable }} puts out a  string representation of the variables content or calls a function.

---

edit:

If you are really in need of getting the inverse value of a boolean, i would suggest to create a simple templatetag for that:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def negate(boolean):
    return (not boolean).__str__()
```

put that in your_app/templatetags/templatetags.py and you can use it in your template like this:

```
{% negate your_variable %}
```

quite costly, i would stick with garnertb's answer.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I think not might only work with `if` tags

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is by using the `add` filter like this:

```
{{ variable_name|add:"-1" }}
```

- `True` is `1`, so, it'll become `0` which is `False`
- `False` is `0`, so, it'll become `-1` which is `True`